# draw rectangle over an arbitrary plane

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Greetings,

I want to draw a rectangle over a polygon belonging
to a arbitrary plane. Given the width (SA) and height (SB) of the
rectangle and the left upper corner (V1) of the rectangle, how
to determine the other vertices (V2, V3 and V4).

[image]

In the case of generic normal vector (all components are nonzero),
the directions (V2-V1) and (V3-V1) must be choosed by dropping
the coordinate of the normal vector with largest magnitude.

Any help is appreciated and welcome,
Best regards,
ricfow

Comment: You should ask this on http://math.stackexchange.com/ , it is a mathematics question. Only once you know the formulas do you write any code, translating a mathematical formula to code is straightforward, so this isn't a programming question.

Comment: In your first sentence you mention a "polygon" but this doesn't appear anywhere in the rest of the question. Can you clarify its role, please?

Comment: The rectangle will be drawn inside a 3D polygon. But this is not important, since what really matters is that the polygon belongs to an arbitrary plane. Do not hesitate to ask more questions if necessary.

Comment: I have to say that I don't understand the bit about "dropping the coordinate of the normal vector with largest magnitude." Maybe if you explained what you are actually trying to achieve, that would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
- First determine the directions to construct the rectangle from the the given point V1.
  The possibilities are (1,0,0), (0,1,0) or (0,0,1). One of the them is eliminated by
  observing the component of largest magnitude of the normal vector. Ex: suppose
  that the normal vector is (0.2 -0.9 0.3). So drop (0,1,0). The other two will be used.
- Project the first direction vector on the plane, using the plane's normal vector. Using
  SA, determine the position of V2. The same idea for V3 and V4.